# JPA select query with where clause

Tags: java, jpa

I want to write a select statement but can't figure out how to write the where clause...

My code:

```
CriteriaQuery query = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
query.select(query.from(SecureMessage.class)).where();
```

This is within a method that I am passing a string to. I want to fetch only the rows that match the value of the string that Im passing to the method.

Comment: Actualy,here is nothing connected to JSF in question.It's a matter of JPA syntax.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I understand, the method parameter should be the parameter of the query.

So, should looks like:

```
Query query = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery("from SecureMessage sm where sm.someField=:arg1");
query.setParameter("arg1", arg1);
```

where `arg1` - your method String parameter

Comment: That didn't work for me mate...in fact that first line of yours doesnt even compile..If I remove the getCriteriaBuilder() it compiles but still doesnt run the query..throws javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException

Answer (score 23):

In Criteria this is something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SecureMessage> query = cb.createQuery(SecureMessage.class);
Root<SecureMessage> sm = query.from(SecureMessage.class);
query.where(cb.equal(sm.get("someField"), "value"));
```

In JPQL:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select sm from SecureMessage sm where sm.someField=:arg1");
query.setParameter("arg1", arg1);
```

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Criteria_API_.28JPA_2.0.29

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple where clauses with entity manager as below. You need to set parameters to each argument.

```
entityManager.createQuery("select u from customer u " +
                    "where u.instituteName=:instituteName " +
                    "and u.applicationName=:applicationName")
                    .setParameter("instituteName", cusSubReq.getInstituteName())
                    .setParameter("applicationName", cusSubReq.getApplicationName()).getSingleResult();
```