# How to use where clause in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a query `Select * from uploadedFile where uid="tesetetesdsfjdsfj";`

I want to write this query in jpa and i have tried this

```
    CriteriaQuery<UploadedFile> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(UploadedFile.class);

    Root<UploadedFile> product = query.from(UploadedFile.class);
    return em.createQuery(query)
         .setFirstResult(0) // offset
         .setMaxResults(10) // limit
         .getResultList();
```

And i dont know how add where condition in this query (`where uid="tesetetesdsfjdsfj";`)

Comment: Please refer this, i hope it will solve your doubt

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136366/jpa-select-query-with-where-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with following snippet:

```
 Query query = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery("from UploadedFile fm where sm.someField=:arg1");
    query.setParameter("arg1", arg1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with following snippet:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UploadedFile> cq = cb.createQuery(UploadedFile.class);
    Root<UploadedFile> product = cq.from(UploadedFile.class);
    cq.select(product);
    cq.where(cb.equal(
         // you can replace product.get(UploadedFile_.uid) with product.get("uid") 
         product.get(UploadedFile_.uid), "tesetetesdsfjdsfj"));
    em.createQuery(cq)
             .setFirstResult(0) 
             .setMaxResults(10) 
             .getResultList();
```

More info on using the API can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjivq)